# How to match the following regex php

Tags: php, regex

I want to write a regex to match only the first and last strings below. So far, I got this regex

```
%[\w]+@\{[\w"]+\}%
```

but it wont match anything:

```
%adasda@{"asdas":"asdas"}% // should match
5% ashdgasjhdgas % //no match
5%ahsdjhasj % // no match
%asdasdas% //should match
```

Comment: Split the string by new-line. Get first and last line from array.

Comment: This should match the first and last line. `(^.*|.*$)` or is `%[\w]+@\{[\w"]+\}%` your regex and your trying to match the 4 strings below?

Comment: @chris85 Yes, I want to match the 4 strings. Sorry, updated my question since it was not clear enough.

Comment: I've made an update, is that correct? e.g. testing against `%adasda@{"asdas":"asdas"}%` etc. Is the rule match `%` no whitespace `%`? I think `^%[^ ]+%$` would work, if so. https://regex101.com/r/P8qM0a/1

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
^%\w+(@[\{"\w\}:]+)*%$
```